# My flow in Power Automate gives an error

Tags: sharepoint-online, power-automate

I try to create a flow in Power Automate from an article I found on the internet:
[John Liu article](http://johnliu.net/blog/2019/2/flowninja-hack-78-modifying-modified-by-and-modified-time-with-microsoft-flow)
But I get an error saying: bad format JSON-stream

What I try to do is: Change a value from the metadata column "Modified By" of a certain row in a Sharepoint list with PowerAutomate.

But it seems the JSON-code isn't correct:

[image]

little question about the uri:

[image]

Does "items(1)" refer to the first row of the sharepoint list?

Greetings, Peter

Comment: Not sure if this is it, but the "k" in "Key" is capitalized in John's blog post but it is not in the JSON you posted.

Comment: Also, John used a Compose action for the user value and a second Compose for the FieldName/FieldValue pairs. I've found that this is sometimes required for string composition to work correctly in Power Automate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Items(1) is not the first line of the shared point list, and "1" is the unique ID of the list item.

[image]